# Global scope - access "this" after firing event listener

Tags: javascript, mootools

I have a mootools class that uploads a file using XHR:

```
var foo = new Class({

    initialize: function() {

        this.bar = 'value';
    },

    upload: function() {

        // This method uploads a file

        ….
        xhr.addEventListener('load', this.uploadComplete, false);
        ….

    },
    uploadComplete: function() {

        // Is getting called on completion of file upload       

        console.log(this.bar); // undefined, but I want to to be 'value'
    }


});
```

I would like to access `this.bar` in the `uploadComplete` method but `this` is not getting passed through in `xhr.addEventListener('load', this.uploadComplete, false);`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use `Function.prototype.bind` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind and http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/Function#Function:bind - which will set the context of this correctly when the event fires.

`xhr.addEventListener('load', this.uploadComplete.bind(this), false);`